# R piped inner join not working

Tags: r, dplyr, inner-join

Can someone explain why this join isnt working? I am adapting code from [here](http://tidytextmining.com/sentiment.html)

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(tidytext)

res<-"Hi my name"%>%strsplit("[[:space:]]")%>%inner_join(get_sentiments("afinn"))
```

I expected to get the intersection of these two lists. What did I do wrong? Note that get_sentiments() returns a list of words of which will have matches for "Hi", "my", "name"

Comment: `dplyr::inner_join()` looks for two tbls to join together. "Hi" "my" "name" is a vector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
"Hi my name is good" %>% 
  str_split("[[:space:]]") %>% 
  unlist() %>% 
  data.frame(word = .,stringsAsFactors = F) %>% 
  inner_join(get_sentiments("afinn"),by = c("word" = "word"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you're already using `tidytext`:

```
res<-
  "Hi my name"%>% 
  tibble() %>% 
  unnest_tokens(word, '.') %>% 
  inner_join(get_sentiments("afinn"))
```